# Configuration of spi slave in device tree files for imx8 board

Tags: linux-device-driver, yocto, spi, device-tree, slave

I am writing an SPI SLAVE driver for an imx8qmlpddr4arm2 board with Yocto. I have problems adding the slave entry on the dts file. In particular, when I test the code, my slave keeps waiting for ever to receive something, even if the other board sends data.

My code:

fsl-imx8qm.dtsi:

```
lpspi0: lpspi@5a000000 {
    compatible = "fsl,imx7ulp-spi";
    reg = <0x0 0x5a000000 0x0 0x10000>;
    interrupts = <GIC_SPI 216 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
    clocks = <&clk IMX8QM_SPI0_CLK>,
         <&clk IMX8QM_SPI0_IPG_CLK>;
    clock-names = "per", "ipg";


    power-domains = <&pd_dma_lpspi0>;
    status = "disabled";
};
```

fsl-imx8qm-lpddr4arm2.dts

```
    pinctrl_lpspi0: lpspi0grp {
        fsl,pins = <
            SC_P_SPI0_SCK_DMA_SPI0_SCK        0x0600004c
            SC_P_SPI0_SDO_DMA_SPI0_SDO        0x0600004c
            SC_P_SPI0_SDI_DMA_SPI0_SDI        0x0600004c
        >;
    };



    pinctrl_lpspi0_cs: lpspi0cs {
        fsl,pins = <
            SC_P_SPI0_CS1_DMA_SPI0_CS1        0x21
        >;
    };



&lpspi0 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_lpspi0 &pinctrl_lpspi0_cs>;
    status = "okay";
    spi-slave;

    slave {
    compatible = "linux,spislave";
    };
};
```

Is correct to set the cs pin as DMA or it is better to set it as GPIO? What is the difference?

And the number 0x21, do I need to change something? I am reading the manual but I cannot understend what I have to modify. Can I use 0x0600004c as the other signals? I have not found anything on the web that could help me.

Thank you in advance a lot!

Comment: For a slave the CS is **input**, that has to generate an event to the driver.

Comment: Thank you. How can I configure it as input?